# Integrate Log(x+1)^m in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I got this question **Integrate ln(x+1)^m for integers m=1to6.**
I've tried this method but I didn't get the result.

```
Integrate[{Log (x + 1)^m, x}, Assumptions -> {m, 1, 6}]
```

The output I got

```
Integrate[{{{Log (1 + x)^4, Log (1 + x)^7, Log (1 + x)^7, 
    Log (1 + x)^7, Log (1 + x)^7}, {Log (1 + x)^6, Log (1 + x)^5, 
    Log (1 + x)^7, Log (1 + x)^7, Log (1 + x)^7}, {Log (1 + x)^6, 
    Log (1 + x)^6, Log (1 + x)^4, Log (1 + x)^7, 
    Log (1 + x)^7}, {Log (1 + x)^6, Log (1 + x)^6, Log (1 + x)^6, 
    Log (1 + x)^4, Log (1 + x)^7}, {Log (1 + x)^6, Log (1 + x)^6, 
    Log (1 + x)^6, Log (1 + x)^6, Log (1 + x)^4}}, x}, 
 Assumptions -> {{{4, 7, 7, 7, 7}, {6, 5, 7, 7, 7}, {6, 6, 4, 7, 
     7}, {6, 6, 6, 4, 7}, {6, 6, 6, 6, 4}}, 1, 6}]
```

And this error

```
Integrate: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in Assumptions->{{{4,7,7,7,7},{6,5,7,7,7},{6,6,4,7,7},{6,6,6,4,7},{6,6,6,6,4}},1,6}.
```

Comment: You might want to ask any further *Mathematica* questions at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Table[Integrate[Log (x + 1)^m, x], {m, 1, 6}]
```

and see if that produces the result you are looking for.  The code in the question misuses `Assumptions` which is really intended for providing extra information for `Integrate` to work with, information such as restrictions on the domain of variables.  `Table` is one simple way of generating a number of results parameterising an expression using an iterator.

Comment: It solved the problem I was facing